# time.sleep freezes the program after forking (Go)

Tags: go

I am forking into "daemon" mode with this function:

```
func daemon(nochdir, noclose int) int {

        ret, _, err := syscall.Syscall(syscall.SYS_FORK, 0, 0, 0)
        if err != 0 {
                maybe_exit_err("Forking", err)
                return -1
        }
        switch ret {
        case 0:
                break
        default:
                os.Exit(0)
        }

        sid, err2 := syscall.Setsid()
        maybe_exit_err(fmt.Sprintf("could not set session: %s", sid), err2)
        if sid == -1 {
                return -1
        }
        if nochdir == 0 {
                os.Chdir("/")
        }
        if noclose == 0 {
                f, e := os.OpenFile("/dev/null", os.O_RDWR, 0)
                if e == nil {
                        fd := int(f.Fd())
                        syscall.Dup2(fd, int(os.Stdin.Fd()))
                        syscall.Dup2(fd, int(os.Stdout.Fd()))
                        syscall.Dup2(fd, int(os.Stderr.Fd()))
                }
        }
        return 0
}
```

The program works fine as long as I do not use `time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)`. After that, it just sits there doing nothing, I have even added writing test string in a loop to a file I opened myself, and nothing is being written there after `time.Sleep` is used (and it works fine if not).

What might be the reason here?

OS: Debian Linux 7.2 x64
go version: 1.2

Comment: Where did you add that `Sleep`?

Comment: @janisz: in a loop that periodically runs a system command (via `exec.Command`). This loop works ok, incl `time.Sleep`, if the program is ran in the foreground (i.e. no call to `daemon` defined above). In bg, right after `time.Sleep`, nothing more is written either to syslog or to the test log I opened myself.

Comment: @janisz: moreover, if I comment out `time.Sleep`, the loop runs correctly even in bg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems I've ran into general issue with runtime: https://code.google.com/p/go/issues/detail?id=6664

UPDATE:

G++1 : https://github.com/sevlyar/go-daemon

SO--1